# LogBack, How to disable in certain environments

Tags: logging, playframework, akka, logback, logback-groovy

I am using the Logback logging for my application, but I want certain logs to not be used based on the environment. For example, I have

```
<logger name="1" level="INFO" />
<logger name="2" level="INFO" />
<logger name="3" level="INFO" />
<logger name="4" level="WARN" />
<logger name="5" level="WARN" />
<logger name="6" level="WARN" />
```

I want to run all of the loggers on my dev environment, but disable the INFOS from logging when I am on my prod environment.

I am not sure how to do this, maybe with some conditional statement?

Answer (score 1):

Just like stated in the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsLogger):

You can provide a default logging configuration by providing a file `conf/logback.xml` (this is the default that Play is looking for).

But if you want custom logging for your `dev` environment or `demo` environment, you would create a `conf/env/logback.demo.xml` and when strting Play, you provide the correct logback.xml:

`start -Dlogger.resource=conf/env/logback.demo.xml`

Comment: Is there a way to do it within one file and not have multiple custom ones?

Comment: I think it is possible, but I have never used it. Play has refactored out the direct dependency to Logback to be a Module. So with Dependency Injection you could use your own or even customise settings on application load, see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsLogger#using-a-custom-logging-framework

Comment: so I used some conditional statements and matched on environment variables and was able to do it